# Debugging data in laravel vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm trying to get data of my projects from 3rd table but i'm not successful with it.

## Logic

In projects single page (*where I show description of each project*), I'm getting `ID` of that project and base on that `ID` I will count total bids and show bidders info.

**Example**

```
Project 1

Bids: 50

Bidders: john, Alex, .....
```

## What I get

1. No data in view
2. Console error

   Method "biders" has already been defined as a data property.

## Code

`script`

```
data(){
   return {
       project : [],
      //other data....
      biders:[], //my biders
      new_biders:'', //add new bidder info
  }
},
mounted() {
  // get logged user info
},
beforeMount(){
  let url = `/api/projects/${this.$route.params.slug}`
  axios.get(url).then(response => {
       this.project = response.data;
       Vue.nextTick(function () {
       $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
      });
   });

   //user info
 },
methods: {
  // getting bids and bidders info from database
  biders() {
    axios.post('/api/projectbids/'+this.project.id)
         .then(res => {
          _.forEach(res.data, function(item){
            this.biders.push(item);
          })
    })
    .catch(error => {
       console.log(error.response)
    });

    // adding new bidder by pusher
    Echo.private('newbidplaced.'+this.project.id)
        .listen('NewBider', (e) => {
        this.biders.push(e.bider);
        alert(e.bider);
        // this.biders.push(e);
     });
   }
}
```

`component`

```
Total Bids {{biders.length}}

<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 mb-3 text-center" v-for="bider in biders" :key="bider.id">
{{bider.name}
</div>
```

`controller`

```
public function projectbids($id){
        $biders = DB::table('projects')
        ->where('projects.id', '=', $id)
        ->join('bids','bids.project_id','=','projects.id')
        ->join('users','users.id','=','bids.user_id')
        ->join('profiles','profiles.user_id','=','users.id')
        ->select('bids.*','users.name','profiles.photo')
        ->get();
        return response()->json($biders, 200);
        event(new NewBider($biders));
}
```

`route`

```
Route::post('/projectbids/{id}', 'Api\ProjectController@projectbids');
```

## Question

1. Why I can't get my bidders info?
2. Where did I do mistake?
3. How can I debug my data to find the part of issue?

Any idea?

Comment: Did you install the vue devtools in your browser?

Comment: @SanderVisser I did, there is nothing for `biders`

Comment: @SanderVisser https://ibb.co/eqJWLz nothing for biders there.

Comment: in the mounted function  `this.biders = this.biders()` I see the defined method in your code but I don't see any invocation of that function

Comment: @SanderVisser with that i'm getting ` Error in render: "TypeError: _vm.biders is undefined"`

Comment: Aaah you defined the function wrong, it should be `bidders: function() {}` the methods property should be object with keys (the function name) and actual function

Comment: that way i'm getting ` Method "biders" has already been defined as a data property.` and `Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: this.biders is not a function"` and `"this.biders is not a function"`

Comment: That makes sense, you can't have methods with the same name as 
properties. you could name the method `getBidders`. This is the nature of javascript

Comment: @SanderVisser results with image https://ibb.co/ew3Rne
 - https://ibb.co/j4we7e

Comment: It should be `mounted: function() {` you can see the explanation here https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Instance-Lifecycle-Hooks note the warning ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178277/discussion-between-sander-visser-and-mafortis).

Comment: @SanderVisser like this? `mounted: function() { this.biders = this.getBidders(); },` result is same `Error in render: "TypeError: _vm.biders is undefined"`

Comment: Can we move this to chat?

Answer (score 0):

The console error is helpful in this situation.
`biders` is defined as a data property AND as a method. Try changing your method name to something like `getBiders`. There may be some further issues down the line, but that is why you are getting the console errors.